# add subtitle to kablextra in R markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra, subtitle

for reporting in R-Markdown pdf: 
I want to either break the title line in kbl() table from the desired point ( which I do not know how to since \n does not do the job) OR add a subtitle under the main title.

````
```{r}
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(101, 4), rep(202, 3)),
                status = c("a","b","c","d", "a", "b", "c"),
                wt = c(100,200,100,105, 20,22,25),
                ht = c(5.3,5.2,5,5.1, 4.3,4.2,4.1)
)

df %>%
  kbl(caption = "Main Title Main Title Main Title Main Title Main Title 
      Main Title Main Title Main Title Main Title Main Title Main Title",
      align = "c") %>%
  kable_styling()
```
````

[image]

Any idea or reference will be highly appreciated.

***EDIT.*** If I add `format="pandoc"`, the extra header will disappear and footnote loses its style.

```
df %>%
  kbl(caption = "Main Title Main Title Main Title Main Title \nMain Title 
      Main Title Main Title Main Title Main Title \nMain Title Main Title",
      align = "c",
      format = "pandoc") %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", " ", "params" = 2)) %>%
  add_footnote(c("note1", "note2"),
               notation = "number")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With the caption package and `escape = FALSE` you can use latex directly for the `caption` argument to get a subtitle...

By way of explanation:
`\\\\` creates a line break
`\\` is required to escape LaTeX `scriptsize`: which lets the application know this is a latex command to set the font size. If you do not need to change the font size then just miss out `\\scriptsize`.

````
---
title: "table subscript title"
output: pdf_document

header-includes:
- \usepackage{caption}
---


```{r}
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(101, 4), rep(202, 3)),
                status = c("a","b","c","d", "a", "b", "c"),
                wt = c(100,200,100,105, 20,22,25),
                ht = c(5.3,5.2,5,5.1, 4.3,4.2,4.1)
)

kbl(df, caption = "Main Title\\\\
      \\scriptsize subscript title  subscript title subscript title\\\\
      \\scriptsize subscript title line 2  subscript title  line 2 subscript title  line 2",
      align = "c",
      escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling() %>%
  add_header_above(c(" ", " ", "params" = 2)) %>%
  add_footnote(c("note1", "note2"),
               notation = "number")

    ```
````

[image]

Comment: Nice! is there a way to keep kablestyling() style when using this package?

Comment: What do you mean by the kablestyling() style ? Could you please state the difference between what is produced using the code in the answer and your expectation?

Comment: I've had quick look at `kable_styling()`. The options seem to be related to the body of the table rather than the caption. Put another way it seems as if caption properties are independent of `kable_styling()`.  Let if know what your interpretation is.

Comment: after hours of working on this, I still can not figure out why I can not get what you get. \\\\ works( break the line ). adding \\ causes error( whi I do not need at this point). but Why \\\\ makes the caption aligned to left when I run exactly what you gave me?

Comment: Have you tried to copy and paste the entire answer into a fresh rmarkdown document? including the yaml header? I have added more explanation to the question and finally added an image of the output.

Comment: Yes. and I have no idea what can cause not getting your nice output :( .

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit odd. I get this result on a windows version of R (version 4.2.0) and using RStudio (2022.02.1 Build 461) as the IDE and kableExtra version 1.3.4. Not really sure what to suggest. Other things which impact on Rmarkdown is Pandoc and the latex engine but these are things I do not really understand. In the past when I've had problems as a last resort I've uninstalled everything and  reinstalled applications and packages but this is a resort of desperation. I'm not sure what else to suggest, do you have a colleague or  friend with R on their computer to try it out?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `format = "pandoc"` in your `kbl` and use `\n` for subtitle like this:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author"
date: '2022-05-16'
output: pdf_document
---


```{r}
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(id = c(rep(101, 4), rep(202, 3)),
                status = c("a","b","c","d", "a", "b", "c"),
                wt = c(100,200,100,105, 20,22,25),
                ht = c(5.3,5.2,5,5.1, 4.3,4.2,4.1)
)

df %>%
  kbl(caption = "Main Title \n
      subtitle: Blabla",
      align = "c", format = "pandoc") %>%
  kable_styling() 
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Quinten. However, if I have footnotes or extra headers or even more than one \n in caption the output is not interesting. please see my modified post.